Home invasion horror thriller movie ID
A movie about  a home invasion. There were more than 2 men. It was at night and there was a family: a father, mother, teenage daughter, and younger brother. I can remember a scene when they were all locked in the bathroom...actually, I think they were there for quite a while. Then one of the men took the daughter downstairs and the mother was saying don"t you hurt my daughter or something along those lines. I didn't watch any more of it but I want to now. They were horrible scary men.

year of release?

Sounds like the movie, The Purge.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2184339/
In the future, a wealthy family is held hostage for harboring the target of a murderous syndicate during the Purge, a 12-hour period in which any and all crime is legalized.

Your details are actually on the vague side. I can only venture this guess because I've seen the movie.
Fear (1996)?
Starring Mark Wahlberg, Reese Witherspoon, William Petersen, Amy Brenneman and Alyssa Milano.

Nicole Walker (Reese Witherspoon) is a fairly innocent teenager with a
  rebellious streak. Having been kicked out of her mother's house, she
  now lives in the suburbs of Seattle with her well-meaning but
  overbearing father Steven (William Petersen) and his new family:
  second wife, Laura (Amy Brenneman); Toby (Christopher Gray), Laura's
  preteen son from her first marriage. At a rave, Nicole meets David
  McCall (Mark Wahlberg), who has borderline personality disorder and
  antisocial features. She is swept off her feet by his sweet, polite
  nature. Steven seems to like David at first but gradually comes to
  mistrust him; Steven also gets angry when Nicole violates her curfews
  to spend more time with David. Eventually, while Steven and Laura are
  on a business trip, Nicole and David have sex at her home...flagrantly
  disobeying a house rule about unsupervised guests. One day, David
  scares Nicole by assaulting her friend Gary (Todd Caldecott) upon
  seeing them hug each other. He shoves Nicole to the ground when she
  tries to stop him, giving her a black eye. Nicole ends things with
  David, leaving him crushed, but her father's now-intense opposition to
  David paradoxically drives her to accept David's apologies. Steven
  suspiciously checks into David's background. He finds out that David
  spent his early life with various foster families, until getting
  arrested and/or institutionalized. When David turned 18, he was
  released from foster care.
David's obsession with Nicole turns increasingly violent; he carves
  "Nicole 4-ever" into his chest. Then David sees Nicole hugging Gary
  again, and gets jealous. Nicole goes with Toby and Laura to the mall;
  they invite Gary along, but he has to get home. David sees Gary
  walking alone through the woods, and kills him in a jealous rage by
  snapping Gary's neck. David also vandalizes Steven's prized Mustang
  and leaves a taunting note to him: "Now I've popped both your
  cherries". Steven breaks into David's house, where he finds an obscene
  shrine that David has built for Nicole...along with a box containing:
  a vandalized bracelet, which read "Daddy's Girl" but has been changed
  to "David's Girl"; a pair of Nicole's underwear; a defaced family
  photo that finds Steven's face and head replaced with David's. Steven
  trashes the house in a rage. David returns home and promptly concludes
  that Steven has been there. He determines to break into the Walker
  residence, with the help of his equally violent friends: Hacker (Gary
  Riley), Knobby (Jed Rees), Logan (Tracy Fraim), and Terry (Jason
  Kristofer). A distraught Margo is at Nicole's house also, having
  come to inform the Walkers that Gary has been found dead in the woods.

Read the rest of the movie summary at the given wiki link.
Some movie clips: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4E886D730161A45F
Trailer: 


